# Next.JS Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm encountering a hydration error in Next.JS 14, where the UI initially rendered on the server doesn't match the client-side rendering. I suspect this might be due to the use of new Date() which could be generating different values on the server and client. How can I resolve this issue while maintaining its presence in my layout page?

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      <footer>
        <p>Page Rendered on - </p>
        {new Date().toLocaleDateString()}
      </footer>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: try with window.onload like
 useEffect(() => {
    window.onload = () => {
      const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      console.log('Date>>', currentDate);
    };
  }, []);

Comment: remove html tag and use <div>... the error you have received means you are not following the template of the next

Comment: but isn't <html> the whole purpose of next.js Page? Unlike react where application rendered to one html, this serve multiple. 
I am new to this thing

Comment: According to the official website: By default, Next.js pre-renders every page. This means that Next.js generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done by client-side JavaScript. Pre-rendering can result in better performance and SEO.

Comment: Can you post this as official answer to help the community?

Comment: **Hydration means** is when React converts the pre-rendered HTML from the server into a fully interactive application by attaching event handlers.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot Naveen. I posted your answer below.

Comment: Happy to see that. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @Naveen Nizam in the comments for the guidance.

The issue originated from a deviation from Next.js's current template guidelines. Instead of utilizing a  tag as the primary container, I mistakenly used an  tag, a practice from older Next.js versions.

The following code rectified the problem:

```
return (
  <div lang="en">
    ...
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there might be different reasons causing this error. While my situation is a bit different from yours, it might help someone facing the exact same error in the future.

Turns out, the `<link>` tags in my `layout.js` were causing the issue. They were using a deprecated approach.

**What I had:**

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css)" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css)" />
      
      <body className={inter.className}>

        <Appy>
          <RootOfAllClientSide>
            {children}
          </RootOfAllClientSide>
        </Appy>

      </body>
      
    </html>
  );
}


Updated to:

import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">

      <body className={inter.className}>

        <Appy>
          <RootOfAllClientSide>
            {children}
          </RootOfAllClientSide>
        </Appy>

      </body>

      
    </html>
  );
}
```